# what's the difference between [[ ],[ ],[ ]] and 3*[[ ]] in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a beginner in programming, and I'm trying to write code for transposing a matrix. When I run the below code, a logic error occurs:

```
def transpose(matrix):
   x=0
   trans=len(matrix[0])*[[]]
   for list in matrix:
       for element in list:
           trans[x].append(element)
           x+=1
       x=0
   return trans
transpose([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
```

Output: `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]`

But when I replace line 3 with `trans=[[ ],[ ],[ ]]` the code works good! What's the difference between `[[ ],[ ],[ ]]` and `3*[[ ]]`? Thanks

Comment: You should try to take as small parts of your code as possible, to understand it ... try: 
`a  = 3*[[]]`
`a[0].append(1)`
`print a`
-> you see?

Comment: yes I got it and edit my code, It work good

def transpose(matrix):
    x=0
    lis=[]
    b=len(matrix[0])
    while b!=0:
        lis.append([])
        b-=1
    for list in matrix:
        for element in list:
            lis[x].append(element)
            x+=1
        x=0
    return lis